# Division Operator Behavior

Tags: php

This will be a basic question. But I'm confused. Can you please explain why the following results as output.

When I tried

```
$num = 012;
$result = $num / 4;
var_dump( $result);
```

**Result**

```
float(2.5)
```

Also When I tried with

```
$num = 09;
```

**Result**

```
int(0)
```

please explain this.

Comment: `10 / 4` = 2.5 ; And `09` is an invalid octal number.

Comment: [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) - `Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +).` and `To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero).`